# Transfer offline map data to another app?

Tags: android, here-api

I am developing android app which is based on offline navigation system the reason behind using offline map is, internet is very expensive on our country. So, I am thinking of Here Map.

My use case is to share downloaded map file into other devices through the wifi direct P2P and load it in the absence of internet connection.

So, my question is:
1. Is it possible to transfer downloaded offline map file from one app to another app.
2. Will it be any litigation issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you put your offline map in your res folder?

Comment: @MehranZamani actually the map data can vary, so it will not work, anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two apps, both using HERE maps the Android SDK already shares the same maps database. There is no need to move the map data.

If you transfer the map data from one device to another that is not documented nor supported. It may lead to some un-forseen issues and will not be supported by the HERE team.

Comment: Ya both app has Here Map SDK basically to work in offline mode, for that  we've to download map right? So here I just want to share downloaded map data from one android device to another. Is it possible? Thanks for your response